# Compare input file Excel (one or more columns will be in excel) and compare same columns in database and return unmatched data and export it to excel

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to create a small application to get data from database and export it to excel.

I want to compare input file Excel (one or more columns will be in excel) and compare same columns in database and return unmatched data and export it to excel.

For example if excel file has Columns: Account,Account Id

Database may have columns : Account,Account Id, Name,Address

process should compare Account and Account ID then return Account ID which are not in database.

Also file may contain huge data.

Please advise how to compare and extract data to excel using Java only.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve  this by  importing Apache POI library and have it in your build path
I find this source very useful [Comparing two excel inputs](http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2015/03/compare-excel-sheets-using-java.html#.WyoIC1VKjIV)

Comment: I knew i can do using POI library but i need the full logic.